# Did the phrase "to make money" originate in the English language?

Tags: phrases, expressions, american-english, history

I am currently reading *Atlas Shrugged* by Ayn Rand and I came across an interesting paragraph related to the English language and its history.

> If you ask me to name the proudest distinction of Americans, I would choose—because it contains all the others—the fact that they were the people who created the phrase ‘to make money.’ No other language or nation had ever used these words before; men had always thought of wealth as a static quantity—to be seized, begged, inherited, shared, looted or obtained as a favor. Americans were the first to understand that wealth has to be created. The words ‘to make money’ hold the essence of human morality.

Is this a true piece of history? Did we create the phrase and the idea of "making money"?

Comment: ***To make money*** . In all likelihood this idiom has existed in many languages across many centuries of time. - https://www.quora.com/Was-the-phrase-to-make-money-originally-coined-as-an-American-English-idiom

Comment: I bet the Romans and Greeks made coins = money, long before the British or the Americans (1776) ever did.

Comment: To make money "earn pay" is first attested mid-15c. Etymonline http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=m&p=42

Comment: I don't know about "making money" but the idea that wealth can be created is relatively new and comes from Adam Smith's *The Wealth of Nations (1776)*. Adam Smith himself was Scottish, but Americans were among the first to base their economy on capitalism - so the claim is not entirely without merit.

Comment: @michael.hor257k That's kind of what I was thinking. We may not have been the first to use the phrase, but we may have been the first to use it in the way that we now describe "the american dream" today.

Comment: @michael.hor257k -  "the idea that wealth can be created is relatively new". Really?? For sure  nobody cared about being reach before Americans in the 18th century.

Comment: @user5661402 - I suggest you post this question on the Economics SE site. It would receive a more appropriate answer there. https://economics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Josh There is a difference between getting richer by making someone else poorer and getting richer by creating wealth that did not exist before. Put your sarcasm aside and read for example [*Sapiens: A Brief History of Humankind*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapiens:_A_Brief_History_of_Humankind) where this is explained much better than I ever could.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - whatever me and you think, this is not an ELU issue. BTW what about Venice in the 16th century, Spain a bit later..and so on.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This question belongs on Economics SE

Comment: @ Josh "*this is not an ELU issue.*" Then I suggest you drop it. I already suggested how you can expand your understanding of the matter - I certainly don't intend to hold a seminar here in the comments.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - thanks I gave you my advice in return.

Comment: @user5661402 I agree. I would also point out that AFAIK the phrase *to make money* does not exist in any other language except as a literal translation of the American (and I stress: American, not English) term.

Comment: Rand's use of "to make money" means neither to earn pay nor to manufacture coins.

Comment: @Xanne I think we understand that. She means to create wealth that didn't exist before.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates primarily to languages other than English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

**First,** this question has already been asked and answered [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10894/did-americans-coin-the-phrase-to-make-money) with the conclusion that Americans did not, in fact, invent it and it is as least as old as Roman times.

**Second,** Ayn Rand did not come up with the idea that Americans invented the phrase *to make money*.  As noted [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=14&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8k7u2yIHVAhVJFz4KHcptBhg4ChAWCC0wAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fthrowgrammarfromthetrain.blogspot.com%2F2011%2F01%2Fmaking-money-good-english-or-all.html&usg=AFQjCNHtA0rSkO54m00WzUbSq43PRDlvxg)

> language watchers in the 19th century made the same claim - as an
> accusation, not a boast. "Making money," had it been American, would
> have been just the sort of crass commercial lingo Americans were
> thought to enjoy.

So this was kind of a *Yankee Doodle* moment where Rand was taking an accusation that the British had been making and turning it around, being proud of it, if it were true.

**Third,** even though it's not literally true, it could be argued to be metaphorically true.  The book *Man in the Place of the Gods: What Cities Mean* states:

> we can certainly say that the American attitude toward money is one of
> respect for the entrepreneur who thinks up a new way to create more
> real wealth - wealth that never existed before.  Just getting money,
> or just moving money around, is not the same thing as creating new
> real wealth that didn't exist before an entrepreneur invented a new
> product or a new service, or a new, more efficient way of doing
> something.

Thus in the same way one might say *the American Spirit* is true and unique, then Rand's assertion is metaphorically true in that way.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis. I somewhat interpreted it as your 3rd point.